# Script read the output to run the next command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am unable to do this, as I am new to scripting, I need a script which should give run on all server mentioned in a file.

First it should login to the server
1st command is `netstat -tulpun | grep -i port` (port & server list are in the same file)

I may get 3 to 4 output here but I need only 25 port output not the others

```
# netstat -tulpun | grep -i 25   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN    25/sendmail  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19258               0.0.0.0:*
```

2nd command is `ps -ef | grep` the PID which I get from the `netstat` command

the output should look as mentioned below

```
=====  
Server1  
Port 1311  
root      8063  8062  0  2014 ?        00:08:06 /opt/dm_cd -run  

=====  
Server2  
Port 1311  
root      6844  6843  0  2014 ?        00:20:22 /etc/bin/linux/ds -run  

=====  
Server3  
Port 8000  
applmgr   1505  4215  0  2014 ?        00:05:44 /app/Apache/bin/httpd -d   

=====   
Server4  
Port 1311  
root      8122  8121  0  2014 ?        01:30:36 /opt/dsvcd -run  

=====  
Server5  
Port 1888  
root     10097 10096  0  2014 ?        01:29:00 /etc/32d -run  


while read -r -u10 server port line  
do  
  echo ==========  server: "$server" port: "$port"  ==========  
  ssh -qn "$server" "netstat -tulpun | grep -E \"\b$port\b\"" | awk '{print $7}' | grep "/" | awk -F "/" '{print $1}'  
  echo  
done 10< demo  

 netstat -tulpunt | grep -E ":25 " | awk '{print $7}' | grep "/" | awk -F "/" '{print $1}' | xargs -I % bash -c 'echo Port % && ps -ef | grep % && echo ' | grep -v grep
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am unable to do this, I need help from scripting specialist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no service running on port 25, but I have service on port 5433, so I will use in this port for demo.

**My environment**

```
$ ps -ef | grep ':5433'
daniel@synapse:~$ ps -ef | grep 5433
daniel    2824  1967  1 12:36 ?        00:05:43 /opt/vertica/bin/vertica -D /vertica/dev/v_dev_node0001_catalog -C dev -n v_dev_node0001 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -P 4803 -Y ipv4
daniel    9455  2702  0 20:27 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 5433
```

---

We should avoid usage in `grep`, otherwise you will get garbage-lines with `grep` in output.

So how we can get a desired output?

- with `lsof` extract a process id (application PID)
- with `ps` get desired output

**Demo:**

```
$ ps -p $(lsof -ti tcp:5433) o user=,pid=,ppid=,c=,stime=,tty=,time=,command=
daniel    2824  1967  1 12:36 ?        00:05:53 /opt/vertica/bin/vertica -D /vertica/dev/v_dev_node0001_catalog -C dev -n v_dev_node0001 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -P 4803 -Y ipv4
```

As we can see output is identical to `ps -ef | grep ${PID}` and no garbage lines with `grep`.

And now we are ready to write a final script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# author: Daniel Leybovich

# list of hosts to check
declare -a CLUSTER=(localhost synapse 127.0.0.1 46.210.138.27)

# port
LOOKUP_PORT=5433

# run main task
for HOST in ${CLUSTER[@]}
do
    echo "===="
    echo "HOST: ${HOST}"
    echo "PORT: ${LOOKUP_PORT}"
    ssh -x ${HOST} "ps -p $(lsof -ti tcp:5433) o user=,pid=,ppid=,c=,stime=,tty=,time=,command="    
done

# we are done
exit 0
```

And here is an output of script:

```
daniel@synapse:/tmp$ ./reds.sh
====
HOST: localhost
PORT: 5433
daniel    2824  1967  1 12:36 ?        00:06:01 /opt/vertica/bin/vertica -D /vertica/dev/v_dev_node0001_catalog -C dev -n v_dev_node0001 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -P 4803 -Y ipv4
====
HOST: synapse
PORT: 5433
daniel    2824  1967  1 12:36 ?        00:06:01 /opt/vertica/bin/vertica -D /vertica/dev/v_dev_node0001_catalog -C dev -n v_dev_node0001 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -P 4803 -Y ipv4
====
HOST: 127.0.0.1
PORT: 5433
daniel    2824  1967  1 12:36 ?        00:06:01 /opt/vertica/bin/vertica -D /vertica/dev/v_dev_node0001_catalog -C dev -n v_dev_node0001 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -P 4803 -Y ipv4
====
HOST: 46.210.138.27
PORT: 5433
daniel    2824  1967  1 12:36 ?        00:06:01 /opt/vertica/bin/vertica -D /vertica/dev/v_dev_node0001_catalog -C dev -n v_dev_node0001 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -P 4803 -Y ipv4
```

Modify script to your need.

**EDIT**

I modified a script.

**File** `hosts.txt`:

```
daniel@node1:5433
johns@node1:4803
johns@node2:5444
johns@node3:4803
daniel@node4:80
```

**Script** `reds.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# author: Daniel Leybovich

# file with lookup params
HOSTS_FILE=${1}


# run main task
for LINE in $(cat ${HOSTS_FILE})
do
    USER=$(echo ${LINE} | cut -d'@' -f1)
    HOST=$(echo ${LINE} | cut -d'@' -f2 | cut -d':' -f1)
    PORT=$(echo ${LINE} | cut -d':' -f2)
    echo "===="
    echo "HOST: ${HOST}"
    echo "USER: ${USER}"
    echo "PORT: ${PORT}"
    ssh "${USER}@${HOST}" -x \
        "ps -p $(lsof -ti tcp:${PORT}) o user=,pid=,ppid=,c=,stime=,tty=,time=,command="
done

# we are done
exit 0
```

**Output**

```
daniel@synapse:/tmp$ ./reds.sh /tmp/hosts.txt
====
HOST: node1
USER: daniel
PORT: 5433
daniel    2934  1902  1 13:51 ?        00:00:31 /opt/vertica/bin/vertica -D /vertica/dev/v_dev_node0001_catalog -C dev -n v_dev_node0001 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -P 4803 -Y ipv4
====
HOST: node1
USER: johns
PORT: 4803
daniel    2932  1902  0 13:51 ?        00:00:00 /opt/vertica/spread/sbin/spread -c /vertica/dev/v_dev_node0001_catalog/spread.conf
====
HOST: node2
USER: johns
PORT: 5444
daniel    1353  1345  0 13:48 ?        00:00:18 /opt/vertica/oss/python/bin/python ./simply_fast.py
====
HOST: node3
USER: johns
PORT: 4803
daniel    2932  1902  0 13:51 ?        00:00:00 /opt/vertica/spread/sbin/spread -c /vertica/dev/v_dev_node0001_catalog/spread.conf
====
HOST: node4
USER: daniel
PORT: 80
daniel    2484  1902  5 13:48 ?        00:02:18 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

Regards

Comment: Daniel, as I said the port and the server list is mentioned in the file. there are more then 500+ host and their related port which i need to scan with netstat -tulpun command, this command will give me the output of Process ID PID. that PID should be used to run the ps -ef command in such a way that only the PID output should be visible

Comment: @Red's And what a problem to declare an array with 1000+ hosts? About how to do it Im not agree, because there are many ways how you can implement it, but you freely do not accept my answer.

Comment: @Red's I modified a script, now it gets file with hosts as argument. Also I parametrized a `user`, `host` and `port` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with

`netstat -tulpun`

Pipe into grep, but also include the colon and a space to exclude the ports with 25 in it:

`grep ":25 "`

Then pipe that into AWK to display the seventh column

`awk '{print $7}'`

Take only the ones with a slash in it (not the only dashes)

`grep "/"`

Then take the PID

`awk -F "/" '{print $1}'`

Piping all that gives all process IDs

`netstat -tulpunt | grep ":25 " | awk '{print $7}' | grep "/" | awk -F "/" '{print $1}'`

Now pipe that into xargs to execute a command with that as arguments

`netstat -tulpunt | grep ":25 " | awk '{print $7}' | grep "/" | awk -F "/" '{print $1}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo Port % && ps -ef | grep % && echo '`

Something like that? Try to understand each step to see what is happening.

Edit: to loop through a list of servers, create a bash file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat serverlist.txt | while read line
do
   ssh $line "netstat -tulpunt | grep ':25 ' | awk '{print $7}' | grep '/' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo Port % && ps -ef | grep % && echo "
done
```

Save to `something.sh` and execute with

`./something.sh`

It loops through a list of servers in a file like this

```
user1@server1.com
user2@server2.com
...
```

If you need to give a password, you can do this:

```
user1:pass1@server1.com
user2:pass2@server2.com
...
```

I did not test this though, so there might be a syntax error somewhere :)

Comment: But how can run this on all the server list mentioned in the file, they are like 500+ host.
Can you suggest?

Comment: You can do `ssh user@server.com 'some command'` to execute a command on a server and put that in a loop to do it for each server

Comment: excluding this i am getting the perfect output.

Comment: So far I have done this can you please check the question. I am getting the process id but unable to use "xargs" command

Comment: I have included something about the server loop. You can try to change the "sh" into "bash"?

Comment: Ya i got it, but still the xargs is not working properly. the process ID is different & the xargs output is different

Comment: Ah, I made a typo, the `{}` should be a `%`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Still I am getting this output "root     31878 31877  0 14:35 pts/35   00:00:00 bash -c ps -ef | grep -E 1399
"